# Java Generic types and equals values return by generic methods?

Tags: java, generics, compare, equals

I have following code:

```
public class SimpleHashMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V>{

static final int SIZE = 997;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
LinkedList<MapEntry<K, V>>[] buckets =
        new LinkedList[SIZE];

public V put(K key, V value)
{
    V oldValue = null;
    int index = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % SIZE;
    if(buckets[index] == null)
        buckets[index] = new LinkedList<MapEntry<K, V>>();
    LinkedList<MapEntry<K, V>> bucket = buckets[index];
    MapEntry<K, V> pair = new MapEntry<K, V>(key, value);
    boolean found = false;
    ListIterator<MapEntry<K, V>> iter = bucket.listIterator();
    int probes = 0;
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        MapEntry<K, V> iPair = iter.next();
        probes++;
            if(iPair.getKey().equals(key)){
                oldValue = iPair.getValue();
                iter.set(pair); //zastapienie starego nowym
                found = true;
                System.out.println("Colision at: " + iPair + " : " + probes + (probes == 1 ? " probe " : " probes ") 
                                        + "needed"); 
                break;
            }
    }

    if(!found)
        buckets[index].add(pair);
    return oldValue;
}

    public V remove(Object o)
{
    V removed = null;
    if(this.get(o) != null)
    {
        int index = Math.abs(o.hashCode()) % SIZE;
            for(MapEntry<K, V> pair : buckets[index])
            {
                if(pair.getKey().equals(o))
                {
                    removed = pair.getValue();
                    buckets[index].remove(buckets[index].indexOf(pair));
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    return removed;
}

@Override
public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
    Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> set = new HashSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>();
    for(LinkedList<MapEntry<K, V>> bucket : buckets){
        if(bucket == null) continue;
        for(MapEntry<K, V> mpair : bucket)
            set.add(mpair);
    }
    return set;
   }
}
```

I'm interestring in it's method:

```
    public V remove(Object o)
{
    V removed = null;
    if(this.get(o) != null)
    {
        int index = Math.abs(o.hashCode()) % SIZE;
            for(MapEntry<K, V> pair : buckets[index])
            {
                if(pair.getKey().equals(o))
                {
                    removed = pair.getValue();
                    buckets[index].remove(buckets[index].indexOf(pair));
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    return removed;
}
```

When we create instance of above class parametrized in this way:

```
SimpleHashMap<String, String> m = 
            new SimpleHashMap<String, String>();

add some elements by putAll method...;
```

Why I can't do:

```
if(this.get(o).equals(o))
```

instead of:

```
if(this.get(o) != null)
```

I know of errasing types on compile level, but if above .equals means that we compare two Object types, so we compare address, not value. OK, it is logical.
But what we compare here:

```
if(pair.getKey().equals(o))
```

It looks like we comparing two String types. Now I'm confused, could someone explain to me how exactly this works in this cases? Sorry for my english. I hope someone help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: MapEntry is own type. It implements Map.Entry interface.

Comment: I don't understand your question or the relevance to all that code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've analyzed the code and I understand everything. Everything what I wanted to know it's connected with type errasing.

Comment: What about it? That's a broad subject. Clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter for `remove(Object o)` is a *key*, so `if(pair.getKey().equals(o))` compares the pair's key to the key parameter (compare apples to apples), but `this.get(o)` returns a *value*, so `if(this.get(o).equals(o))` is comparing a value to a key, which is meaningless (compare apples to oranges).